# App won't display results inserted by api, will for ones inserted by site

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a simple app that allows you to submit a name on a webpage. The name and a timestamp are inserted in my GAE datastore. Below the submission box, all of the previously submitted names and timestamps are displayed. I also created an api that will also insert a name and timestamp into the datastore. For some reason, only the names submitted by the webapp are displaying on the webpage.

```
def person_timestamp_key(person_timestamp):
  return ndb.Key('Person Timesteamp', person_timestamp)

class Person(EndpointsModel):
  name = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
  timestamp = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

Insert from the app:

```
def post(self):
    person_timestamp = 'person_timestamp'

    # Sets entity for comments
    person = Person(parent=person_timestamp_key(person_timestamp))

    name = self.request.get('name')

    if name and not name.isspace():
        person.name = name
        person.put()
```

Insert from the API:

```
  @Person.method(path='healthsecure', http_method='POST', name='person.insert')
  def PersonInsert(self, person):
    person.put()
    return person
```

Query to display names on site:

```
names_query = Person.query(
        ancestor=person_timestamp_key(person_timestamp)).order(+Person.timestamp)
names = names_query.fetch()
```

In the datastore, the only difference between entities from the site and entities from the api are that WriteOps on entities from the API is 5 and from the site is 6. I wouldn't think that would affect the results of the query, but I'm still learning. Any ideas?

Comment: how does your API-inserted entity get its ancestor and timestamp (which you use in your query)?

Comment: @DanCornilescu I added some additional code above. The timestamp is added automatically. I only have the ancestor on the app query. I pulled this from a previous project. If its necessary, should I add it to the API query? If not necessary, could I remove that from the app side?

Comment: Check in the Datastore viewer if the entity created by the API is indeed created, if it has a parent and if the parent matches the ancestor key in your query. Side note: I see a typo in `Person Timesteamp` Key kind, check if it doesn't cause a mismatch between the post and API methods.

Comment: @DanCornilescu the entity created by the API is definitely being created according to the datastore viewer. I fixed the typo - thanks for catching that. The page still isn't showing the names submitted via the API however. I can't figure out how to set a parent for the API method. I've tried: @Person.method(path='healthsecure', http_method='POST', name='person.insert')
  def PersonInsert(self, person):
      person = Person(parent=person_timestamp_key(person_timestamp))
      person.put()
      return person but this just adds an entity with "none" for the name.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest funneling both API and standard interfaces into a common method of writing to the DB to ensure consistency. But I haven't actually looked at the API side at all, so I have no clue if that's even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this with the suggestion from @Dan Cornilescu. I believe the underlying issue was that I wasn't setting the ancestor key for the API insert. To resolve this, I wrote 1 method for inserting into the DB, then the site and the API use that method.

DataStoreWrite.py:

```
def person_timestamp_key(person_timestamp):
return ndb.Key('Person Timestamp', person_timestamp)


class Person(EndpointsModel):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    timestamp = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

def do_insert(self, name):
    person_timestamp = 'person_timestamp'
    # Sets entity
    person = Person(parent=person_timestamp_key(person_timestamp))

    person.name = name

    person.put()
```

main.py:

```
def post(self):

    name = self.request.get('name')

    person = DatastoreWrite.Person()

    if name and not name.isspace():
        person.do_insert(name)

    self.redirect('/')
```

main_api.py

```
@endpoints.api(name='healthsecure', version='v1',
           allowed_client_ids=[WEB_CLIENT_ID, ANDROID_CLIENT_ID,
                               IOS_CLIENT_ID, endpoints.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID],
           audiences=[ANDROID_AUDIENCE],
           scopes=[endpoints.EMAIL_SCOPE])
class HealthSecureApi(remote.Service):
      """healthsecure API v1."""
      @Person.method(path='person', http_method='POST', name='person.insert')
      def PersonInsert(self, person):

          person.do_insert(person.name)

          return person
```